# В React input изменяется jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Два скрипта взаимодействуют друг с другом: один написан на React, другой на jQuery. В React-компоненте есть textarea и есть событие onChange, которое изменяет state. Скрипт jQuery изменяет значение textarea, но onChange при этом не срабатывает. Возможно ли как-то вызывать onChange в реакт-компоненте при изменении textarea jQuery-скриптом?

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: `$('textarea').val('bla bla').trigger('change'); //или просто .change()`

Comment: если вы используете реакт, то вам стоит отказаться от jQuery, в нём нет смысла. Всё можно реализовать реактом гораздо проще.

Comment: не срабатывает...  Textarea обернут в реактовский компонент, и onChange задан на нем `<Textarea
                  className={styles.texteditor + " js-chat_form__message"}
                  value={this.props.commentText}
                  onChange={e => {
                    onCommentTextChange(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  onHeightChange={() => this.setState(this.state)}
                  autoFocus
                  ref={(ref: any) => (this.editorRef = ref)}
                  placeholder={this.choosePlaceholder()}
                />`

Comment: Я бы рада, но тогда придется переписывать большой скрипт чужой, а времени на это нет(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js

Answer (score -1):

Нашла ответ. Можно осуществлть доступ к любому методу компонента, если создать ref и присвоить в window.

`ReactDOM.render(<Page ref={(ourComponent) => {window.ourComponent = ourComponent}} />, document.getElementById("app"));
...
//какой-то новый value в скрипте jquery
window.ourComponent.setState(value)`

Источник: https://brettdewoody.com/accessing-component-methods-and-state-from-outside-react/